# Wild Cards in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a SQL Server database that contains a table `address(a_id:int, street:nvarchar(50), apt:nvarchar(50), city:nvarchar(50), state:nvarchar(50), zip:int)`

I have a stored procedure that returns the `a_id` for a specific address.

```
SELECT
    address_id
FROM
     address a
WHERE
    street like '%'+ @street +'%'
    and apt like '%'+ @apt +'%'
    and zip = @zip
```

For example if I put in `1060 West Addison Street Chicago IL 60613` I would want to get the same `a_id` as `1060 W Addison Street Chicago IL 60613` or `1060 W. Addison Street Chicago IL 60613`

As you can see, I tried putting wild cards around the `street` and `apt` columns to account for differences in abbreviations and periods, but it does not work.

Currently only the first example returns an `a_id`, as this is what matches whats in the db exactly

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` operator does not work like you hope it will. If you use `LIKE %Addisson%`, it would return both `West Addison` and `W Addison`, but it cannot return `W Addison` if the input is `West Addisson`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
% - Any string of zero or more characters. - WHERE title LIKE '%computer%' 
finds all book titles with the word 'computer' anywhere in the book title.
```

For your scenario, you might want to check out `full tezxt index search`, which might allow you to accomplish your goal. Specifically, the `CONSTAINABLE` keyword might help you out:

> Searching for Words or Phrases Using Weighted Values (Weighted Term)
>
> You can use CONTAINSTABLE to search for words or phrases and specify a
>   weighting value. Weight, measured as a number from 0.0 through 1.0,
>   indicates the importance of each word and phrase within a set of words
>   and phrases. A weight of 0.0 is the lowest, and a weight of 1.0 is the
>   highest.
>
> The following example shows a query that searches for all customer
>   addresses, using weights, in which any text beginning with the string
>   "Bay" has either "Street" or "View". The results give a higher rank to
>   those rows that contain more of the words specified.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 GO

SELECT AddressLine1, KEY_TBL.RANK  FROM Person.Address AS Address
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Person.Address, AddressLine1, 'ISABOUT
("Bay*", 
         Street WEIGHT(0.9), 
         View WEIGHT(0.1)
         ) ' ) AS KEY_TBL ON Address.AddressID = KEY_TBL.[KEY] ORDER BY 
KEY_TBL.RANK DESC GO
```

> A weighted term can be used in conjunction with any simple term,
>   prefix term, generation term, or proximity term.

Source: [Query with Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx)